# Не работают медиа-запросы в sass

Tags: css, sass, less, media-queries

Вот пример кода

```
@media only screen (max-width: 750px)

  .ic
    display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Всему виной может быть вложенность... Эта проблема и в less 
Смысл такой, если в примере такая конструкция 

        html, body
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           #wrapper
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;

То в css при компиляции записывается так

    html, body{
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
        }
           html, body #wrapper{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
           }
а когда ты задаешь @media


    @media only screen (max-width: 750px)
            #wrapper
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;


что бы изменить только wrapper не слушает медиа

надо дописать в медиа и вложенность
@media only screen (max-width: 750px)
    html, body
           #wrapper
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Мысль ясна, попробую пошаманить с вложенностью

Comment: всегда пожалуйста... будь другом, напиши если помогло.. смысл в том, что у меня такое было в less  и помогло... а в sass я не работал, уверен на 99%, что я прав, но все же хотелось бы знать наверняка

Comment: Да конечно , с радостью отпишусь!)хотелось бы чтобы причина была во вложенности))

Comment: Да! заработало но только не в Chome а в Firefox!!  И заработало только с правильной вложенностью!))спасибо!

Comment: рад был помочь!!))

Comment: Ты не в курсе почему не работает в chrome?

Comment: у меня везде заработало с less...  подозреваю, что у sass в хром есть маленькая разница разница в синтаксисе... вот щас сижу читаю для общеuо развития о sass))) если что узнаю, дам знать, но скорее найдешь если погуглить

Comment: Спасибо тебе добряк!))

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width : 1220px),
 only screen and (max-device-width : 1220px) ` вот так работает в хроме)))))

Answer (score 0):

Быть может, проблема есть и со вложенностью, как пишет **Air**, но очевидный косяк - отсутствие `and` в медиа-запросе. Код должен быть таким:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .ic {
    display: inline-block
  }
}
```

Comment: анд должен быть, а чтобы работало во всех браузерах должно быть так `@media only screen and (max-width : 750px), only screen and (max-device-width : 750px)`

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович, `max-device-width` и `max-width` - разные вещи, и должны работать вне зависимости друг от друга во всех браузерах) Почитайте, чем они отличаются.

Answer (score -1):

Поправьте синтаксис:

```
@media only screen (max-width: 750px)
{
  .ic{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Не работает, у меня наоборот ошибку синтаксиса выдает когда есть фигурные скобки`@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)
  .ic{
    display: inline-block` так тоже не работает

Comment: В Sass не используют фигурные скобки. А вот в SCSS...